# How to prevent Mathematica from inserting random line breaks in usage messages?

Tags: output-formatting, usage-messages

I am writing a Mathematica package, and documenting its functions with `::usage` messages. However, when I type `?FunctionName` to view the usage message of a function, Mathematica inserts seemingly random line breaks into the message.

Here is an example (I replaced the letters in the message with `x`'s, because the actual text of the message doesn't matter):

```
test::usage = 
  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxx, xxxxx] xxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx.";
?test
```

The output in Mathematica is as follows:

[image]

For some reason, Mathematica chooses to add a line break in the middle of the sentence, which was not there before, instead of using the entire line width. As a result, the output looks ugly - especially since the first line is significantly shorter than the second line.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Well, there's certainly *a* way: replace all the spaces with `\[NonBreakingSpace]`. But this is bad and I hope there's a better answer.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Thanks, this works, but seems a bit extreme... People have been writing Mathematica packages for decades, am I really the first person to encounter this issue? :O

Comment: @Bill: Thanks, I tired this but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: You can always put your own line breaks (`\n`) in the string where you want them as well. It's obviously not always what you want, but it's easy to do at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem when writing my own package ([OGRe: An Object-Oriented General Relativity Package](https://github.com/bshoshany/OGRe)). My initial solution, which I first posted here, was to convert spaces to `\[NonBreakingSpace]`, which stopped Mathematica from breaking the lines in weird places - but also forced it to break in the middle of words...

Then I found another solution, using a dirty trick where I converted English letters to characters from the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols Unicode block, which are inherently bold and/or italic. But that wasn't a good solution either.

However, [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll), in the comments to my answer, suggested a perfect solution combining his answer and my old answer. My new code for a module that generates a nicely-formatted usage message is as follows:

```
CreateUsageMessage[f_, args_List, msg_String] := (
    Evaluate[f::usage] = ToString[TextCell[Row[{
        ToString[f],
        "[",
        Splice[(Style[#, Bold] &)/@ Riffle[args, ", "]],
        "] ",
        Splice[StringSplit[msg, "`"] /. (ToString[#] -> Style[args[[#]], Bold] & /@ Range[1, Length[args]])]
        }]],
        StandardForm
    ];
);
Attributes[UsageMessage] = HoldAll;
```

I prefer bold for the arguments, but if you want italic, simply replace `Bold` with `Italic`.

Here is an example of using this module:

```
CreateUsageMessage[TList, {ID, indices, coordinatesID}, "lists the unique, non-zero components of the tensor object `1` with the index configuration `2` and in the coordinate system `3`.
`2` should be a list of the form {\[PlusMinus]1, \[PlusMinus]1, ...}, where +1 corresponds to an upper index and -1 corresponds to a lower index.
If the index configuration and/or coordinate system are omitted, the default ones will be used."];
```

This will produce the following usage message:

[image]

Problem solved! Thanks Carl!

Comment: You can just use something like `Row[{Style["f", Bold], "[", Style["arg", Italic], "] is xxx"}]` to get bold and italic letters.

Comment: I tried that, and got an error saying that the usage message must be a string. This is exactly why I had to use this dirty trick in the first place.

Comment: I'm talking about the argument of TextCell, which is inside of ToString.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Thanks, that works perfectly! Please see my new edit :)

Answer (score 5):

I usually discourage the use of [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) strings, but this is a case where it makes sense, since usage messages have to be strings. The key is to format the string as a text cell using [`TextCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCell), since these strings line-break as text. Using a simple string instead formats as an expression. So:

```
test::usage = ToString[
    TextCell["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxx, xxxxx] xxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx."],
    StandardForm
];
```

Then:

```
?test
```

[image]

Comment: +1.  It seems to work as well with `TraditionalForm` as `StandardForm`, but perhaps there's a drawback this example does not show?

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. But why do you usually discourage the use of `StandardForm` strings? And are there any issues that may arise from using `StandardForm` in my usage messages?